# Cannot see FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq

Any Help is much appreciated guys!

under GetProductByID, i am getting an error saying "int does not contain a definition for FirstOrDefault".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using HomebaseSystemNew.Models;

namespace HomebaseSystemNew.Controllers
  {
    public class ProductRepository
   {

    public ProductsController GetProductID(int Pid)
        {
          Product db = new Product();

          return db.Pid.FirstOrDefault(db => db.Pid == Pid);
        }


   }




   }
```

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with MVC3. You are simply using `FirstOrDefault` wrong. `db.Pid` is an `int` but it needs to be enumerable for `FirstOrDefault` to work.

Answer (score 32):

Also You need to add **using System.Linq** namespace to access those methods.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds very unlikely that you want to *start* with a `Product` instance. The correct code is more likely to look like:

```
public Product GetProductByID(int id)
{
    return new DbContext().Products
                          .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Pid == id);
}
```

After all, you don't logically get from *a single product* to a collection of products, let alone from a single product ID to a collection of . You haven't said where your data is or anything like that, but you need to be applying `FirstOrDefault` to a *collection* of products.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it appears that `db.Pid` is an integer (Int32), not an `IEnumerable<T>`.

The `LINQ` operators are defined on `IEnumerable`, not `Int32`.

By default it will be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Well `int` doesn't contain a definition for `FirstOrDefault` because it's not a list type.

You'll need a list of ints for this to work:

```
public ProductsController GetProductID(List<int> Pids)
{
    ....
}
```

or more likely

```
public ProductsController GetProductID(int Pid)
{
    Product db = new Product();

    return db.Products.FirstOrDefault(db => db.Pid == Pid);
}
```

assuming you have a table called `Product` in your database.

Answer (score 0):

`FirstOrDefault` is an extension method on an IEnumerbale or IQueryable, you're trying to call it from an integer.